# when do you prefer to use process based parallelism to thread based parallelism?

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing

As I research about those two concepts I see that threads are easy to manage with little memory and cpu overhead, also switching between threads are also faster. Then the question is, in what cases process based method is the choice? One explicit case is to use of multiple languages in a collaboration then using separate process as sharing a common memory space seems useful. What are the other scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

Distributed systems is a good example for a high level view ... Also look at scaling requirements of an server application. These are 2 places processes play a important role.

You think in terms of threads only when you are programming a module in which all the components are available and accessible in the same process. Threads address most of the requirements for a module's multi-processing.

Processes could be background processes that do a particular task of I/O or monitoring for a long time regardless of the other processes need for that service. Several server applications run as processes and serve requests that come in from the network.